# merge binary strings and convert to decimal in c

Tags: c

The code below will get two integers `X` and `Y` from user, convert them to binary and insert all bits of `Y` after the last set bit in `X`.

example: `10 14`

output: `188`

Explanation:

10 -> 1010
14 -> 1110

10111100 -> 188

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int insertBits(int X, int Y) { 

    int int_to_bin(int k) {
        return (k == 0 || k == 1 ? k : ((k % 2) + 10 * int_to_bin(k / 2)));
    } 
    int a1 = int_to_bin(X);
    int a2 = int_to_bin(Y);
    char msg[20];
    char msg1[20];
    char deal[20];
    sprintf(msg, "%d", a1);
    sprintf(msg1, "%d", a2);
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    for (i = strlen(msg) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (msg[i] == '1') {
            k = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    memcpy(msg, &msg[0], i);
    memcpy(deal, &msg[i], -1);
    strcat(msg, deal);
    printf("%s", strcat(deal, msg1));
}
    
int main() {
    insertBits(10, 20);
}
```

I wrote the code till converting the input to binary and extracted the binarys i dont know how to merge it and convert to decimal.please help me

Comment: To begin with the code you show isn't valid C code. C doesn't have nested functions.

Comment: And `memcpy(deal,&msg[i],-1);` will not work very well! What do you think copying a negative number of bytes will do?

Comment: How did you get 10111100 from 1010 and 1110?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *C doesn't have nested functions* It's another non-portable [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.  Looks like he "insert[ed] all bits of Y [1110] after the    last set bit in X [10*1*0]"

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lets summarize what you have to do,

1. Convert the numbers in 4bit binary and concatenate into a string.
2. After both numbers are done in separate strings concatenate both strings to get new string.
3. Convert the new string in decimal.

This functions converts a single number into 4bit binary string. Call this 2 times and you get two string with 4bit bin number. Now take the two string and concatenate it for getting the final string.

```
const char *byte_to_binary(int x)
{
    static char b[9];
    b[0] = '\0';

    int z;
    for (z = 8; z > 0; z >>= 1)
    {
        strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
    }

    return b;
}
```

Now what if you need more the 4bits. You can see I have initialized `z=8` because 0b0000 1000 in dec is 8. so if you need 5bit then just so `z=16` because 0b0001 0000 is 16 in dec.

For converting string of numbers in decimal, use the basic concept. If bin number is 0b1000, then to convert it to dec you need to do, 1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0.

```
for(sum=0, j=0, s=strlen(num)-1; s >= 0; s--, ++j){
    if(num[s] == '1'){
        sum = sum + pow(2,j);
    }
}
```

This code snippet converts a string of binary in dec. That's it.

P.S. Not giving you full code as time is limited and I guess you are smart enough to figure it out by yourself. Comment for any help.

Comment: I'm afraid your `byte_to_binary` function only handles the last 4 bits of `x` and produces leading zeroes.

Comment: Yeah correct. But it was just the initial approach. Anyone could optimise it

Comment: No: for the OP's purpose, it should handle the whole number, not just the last 4 bits, and should not produce leading zeroes.

Comment: It is not a matter of optimisation, but one of correctness. Optimisation is useless if the code is not correct.

Comment: Well i didn't thought through all the cases. Thankyou for pointing it out.

Comment: Using a static array in the conversion routine is bogus: when you convert both numbers, the second conversion will overwrite the first. `9` digits is not enough for 32-bit integers...

Answer (score 0):

I will give a non portable answer. It will work for x86 + gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int insertBits(int X, int Y) {
    int msb;
    asm("bsrl %1,%0" : "=r"(msb) : "r"(X));
    Y <<= (msb+1);
    return X|Y;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", insertBits(10, 20));
}
```

X=10 => 1010

Y=20 => 10100

Result=330 => 101001010

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is severely limited: if the number is larger than 1023, the conversion will overflow the range of `int`.

You should use `unsigned int` arguments, compute the number of trailing zeroes in `X` and the number of bits in `Y` and the result will be easy to get with shift operations:

```
unsigned int insertBits(unsigned int X, unsigned int Y) {
    int n1, n2;
    unsigned int temp;
    if (X == 0)
        return Y;
    if (Y == 0)
        return X;
    // compute the number of trailing zeroes in X
    for (n1 = 0, temp = X; (temp & 1) == 0; n1++, temp >>= 1)
         continue;
    // compute the number of bits in Y
    for (n2 = 0, temp = Y; temp != 0; n2++, temp >>= 1)
         continue;
    return ((X >> n1 << n2) | Y) << n1;
}
```